# What data type should you use when storing weight (in kg) when it includes both decimals and integers with different lengths?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored weight before in different databases but I used for example, `Decimal (4,2)`, which I assumed would work here but I keep getting the error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.

These are my values I need to store:

[image: the data I need to store]

I'm trying to make it so that there are no excess 0s but still include the integers and decimals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, the range -99.99 - 99.99 is not sufficient for the data you want to store.  And now that the image is in the question, I see values such as 550, which won't fit in `decimal(4, 2)` -- hence the error.

`Numeric`/`decimal` is a very reasonable choice.  Your question isn't clear on the range you want but for, say -9,999.99 - 9,999.99 then use `decimal(6, 2)`; that would be four digits to the left of the decimal and two to the right ("6" digits in total).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I used `decimal(6,2)` and I was getting quite a few 0s at the end so I changed it to `decimal(6,1)`. Now I get this, with less 0s, but still some: https://i.imgur.com/HI40ns2.png . I'll add that `decimal(5,1)` did the same.

Do you know what I could use to remove the excess 0s and just keep the numbers (including the decimals)? 

Sorry I wasn't too clear in my original message. I wasn't sure how to get out what I was trying to ask.

Comment: @RachelD Excess 0's are just a formatting issue, the second number in the datatype tells you the number of digits possible after the `.`

Comment: @Charlieface yeah I'm starting to realize it really doesn't matter because the value is not affected at all... but as this is for school, I'm trying to keep it perfect. Is it even possible to do this in a table?

Comment: @RachelD Perhaps look at the `FORMAT` function. The point here is that your table stores the value as a *number* (with an appropriate precision and scale) not as *text*, you should only format it when displaying it, do *not* store it in `varchar`

Comment: @Charlieface yeah you're right thanks! It seriously doesn't affect it all. Just to clarify, decimal(4,1) would be okay to use if the maximum weight is 999.9, right?

Comment: @RachelD Yes I believe so. You would then not be able to do 9.99 or 9.999 though